# Add an \hline to every \\ using colortbl and/or [table]{xcolor}

Tags: tables, color, colortbl

I'm creating my own tabular environment to speed up my work and to enable others to quickly use my styles and templates.

One of the things I do is force an `\hline` on every row. I accomplish this using the code below

```
\let\tabc@oldnewline\@tabularcr
\def\tabc@newline{\tabc@oldnewline \hline}
\def\@tabularcr{\tabc@newline}
```

to change the behaviour of `\\` to automatically put an `\hline`. This works fine until one uses the package `colortbl`, or `xcolor` with the `table` option. At this point the `\hline`s just disappear. I stripped down my current code to a fairly minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{tabularc}[2][ll]{%
     \let\tabc@oldnewline\tabularcr
     \def\tabc@newline{\tabc@oldnewline \hline}
     \def\tabularcr{\tabc@newline}
  \expandafter\tabular\expandafter{#1}
  \hline
  #2 \\
}{%
  \endtabular
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularc}[llcr]{
  Timmy&
  Timmy&
  Timmy&
  Timmy
}
G & G & G & G \\
obbles & obbles & obbles & obbles \\
\end{tabularc}
\end{document}
```

As long as either of the `\usepackage` lines is present, `\\` will not produce an `\hline`. Remove both lines and there will be `\hline`s between all rows and at the bottom of the table. How can i have `\\` put an `\hline` with the `colortbl`package?

Comment: Somewhat off-topic: Have you considered the possibility that having an `\hline` after every single row may be more of a vice than a virtue?

Comment: @Mico: No I haven't ,really. I just follow the CI guide. Ultimately this will be used with the beamer class ...

Comment: What is a "CI"?

Comment: I commend `booktabs`'s manual to your attention.... It may be a source of needed sanity in a CI-guided world. (I have no more idea what 'CI' is than @Mico.)

Comment: Except you can't sensibly use coloured rows with booktabs…

Comment: @Bernard - A table with multi-colored rows *and* an `\hline` after every single row qualifies as a compound vice, no? :-) Thoroughly understanding the layout philosophy espoused by the user guide of the `booktabs` package, on the other hand, must be a good step on the road to virtue...

Comment: @Bernard I wasn't saying to use `booktabs`. I was recommending its documentation. That has useful information whether you are using it or not. And it might help with the `\hlines`....

Comment: I fully agree with booktabs – a package that I discovered more than 15 years ago. However, in my opinion, one may use coloured rows with a few sparse horizontal lines (even coloured ones, and even some vertical lines! – it's a matter of design).

Comment: @Mico: A CI guide is a "corporate identity" guide. Basically its a set of arbitrary rules with questional reasoning, if any. It dictates what documents always should look like and *have* to look like when shown to people outside the company. I may use LaTeX only under the conditions that my documents always adhere to these rules.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following patch:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newenvironment{tabularc}[1]
 {\patchcmd{\ialign}{\everycr{}}{}{}{}%
  \everycr{#1}%
  \tabular}
 {\endtabular}

\newcommand\addhr{\noalign{\hrule height 0.2mm }}

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{red!50}{blue!50}
\begin{tabularc}{\addhr}{llcr}
Timmy &  Timmy &  Timmy &  Timmy\\
G & G & G & G \\
obbles & obbles & obbles & obbles\\
\end{tabularc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The directive `\usepackage{colortbl}` is redundant, since the instruction `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` already loads the `colortbl` package in a way that's compatible with `xcolor`. See table 1, "Package options", in the user guide of the `xcolor` package.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I just wanted to mimic the same problematic code of the OP to show how it works.